# Server kills my CakePHP console application for no reason

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a console application in CakePHP who selects around 2000 records from a MySQL database. When I launch this application, it gets killed by the system after about 30 seconds.

Code:

```
$id = 404;
$options = array( 'conditions' => array( 'Tablex' => $id ) );

$tablexs = $this->Tablex->find('all', $options);
```

If I instead do this select in my DB manager or I do it in a normal PHP script, it works fine (and is very fast).

```
SELECT * FROM tablexs WHERE id = 404
```

Below is a part of my php.ini on my server online.

However locally on my computer I run a apache server with MySQL & PHP and when I run my CakePHP console application locally it works fine and I only have ; memory_limit = 128M in my php.ini file on my computer.

Like I wrote above, I have no problem to run the same query in a normal PHP console application.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; 
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 300

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; 
max_input_time = 600

; Maximum input variable nesting level
; 
;max_input_nesting_level = 64

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 512M
```

Comment: are you running into your maximum execution time? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I guess `'Tablex' => $id` will be transformed to `WHERE Tablex = 404` but not `WHERE id = 404`... Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a mistake of me :

Code :

    $id = 404;
    $options = array( 'conditions' => array( 'id' => $id ) );

    $tablexs = $this->Tablex->find('all', $options);

Comment: Thank you for your replies, when I do a "dmesg | grep -i memory" I get: Out of memory: kill process, message for my process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This memory limit was all due to the model where my table "Tablex" was linked to another table with a huge amount of data. After changing the model everything was all good.